# Random movements / turbulences - SWIFT

Tags: ios, random, swift, sprite-kit, ios8

I'm developing a game on Iphone and Ipad like a space invaders.

Balloons to destroy are falling from the top of the screen in a straight line.

Here my codes to add them :

```
func addBalloonv(){


    var balloonv:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "ballonvert.png")


    balloonv.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (circleOfRadius: balloonv.size.width/2)
    balloonv.physicsBody.dynamic = true
    balloonv.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory | greenCategory
    balloonv.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = flechetteCategory
    balloonv.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory
    balloonv.physicsBody.mass = 1
    balloonv.physicsBody.restitution = 1
    balloonv.physicsBody.allowsRotation = true


    let minX = balloonv.size.width/2
    let maxX = self.frame.size.width - balloonv.size.width/2
    let rangeX = maxX - minX
    let position:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)

    balloonv.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height+balloonv.size.height)

    self.addChild(balloonv)
```

I have one func by balloon color.

So for the moment they move in straight line and I'm looking for random movements (with turbulences like balloon in air) from the top and both sides.

How can I do that?

Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what the new Physics Fields feature in SpriteKit (as of iOS 8 / OS X Yosemite) is for. These let you apply different kinds of forces to all physics bodies in region, like gravity, drag, and turbulence. See the [`SKFieldNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014163) class docs for details.

Fields are a kind of node, so to get what you're after, you'd add one noise (or turbulence) field to your scene, covering the area that the balloons fall through, and it'll perturb the path of each balloon that passes. The simplest way to do it goes something like this:

```
let field = SKFieldNode.noiseFieldWithSmoothness(0.5, animationSpeed: 0.1)
scene.addChild(field)
```

You'll want to tweak the smoothness, animation speed, and `field.strength` till you get just the level of noise you want. You might also look into whether you want just a noise field, which applies random forces in random directions, or a turbulence field, which does the same thing, but with forces that get stronger when bodies are moving faster.

The above code gets you a field whose region of effect is infinite. You might want to limit it to a specific area (for example, so it doesn't keep knocking your balloons around after they land). I did this to make a field that covers only the top 3/4 of a 300x200 scene:

```
field.region = SKRegion(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100))
field.position = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150)
```

Comment: You know what ? I LOVE YOU !!!
I was pretty sure that's turned around Physics Fields feature. The docs was already open in my screen but I had no idea how initialize it... It's so simple that I'm shame :-D. I'm trying to learn with my first app, but it's very difficult because I don't have good C-langage basis. Do you have advices or documentations for noob ? 

THANK YOU A LOT !!!